# Vectors - Airplane Problems

Tags: vectors

I keep getting the answer wrong for b. I keep getting 1 hour and 25 minutes but the answer is 1 hour and 34 minutes.

And I am also not sure how to work out question c. The answer is 1 hour and 20 minutes. Could you please help?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I don't like to help people that don't show their efforts so far.

Comment: But I did try and I suck at these types of questions.

Comment: Use X and Y axis. Write the $v=s/t$ formulas for each axis, modified with some trigonometry. For example if the vector `V` heads 40⁰ (from X axis) then $V_x=V·cos(40)$.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out